# leader board not working in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

[image]I am trying to make a leader board that tells the player how much cats they have collected. the player has a file and the script counts how many items the file has then displays it on the leaderboard, but it doesn't work(shows the leaderboard but no second row for the amount collected)! Any ideas??

here is my code:

```
`local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local catscollected = player:WaitForChild("catsCollected")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local folder = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    folder.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local catsamount = Instance.new("IntValue", folder)
    catsamount.Name = "Cats Found"
    catsamount.Value = 0
    while wait(0.1) do
        catsamount.Value = 0
        for _, v in pairs(catscollected:GetChildren()) do
            catsamount.Value = catsamount.Value + 1
        end 
    end
end)`
```

Comment: and what is "doesn't work" supposed to mean?  do you expect us to rub our magic crystal balls to find out?

Comment: @Piglet, Wait, you guys don't do that

Comment: I have updated it to how it "doesn't work", is that enough  clarification? @Piglet

Answer (score 0):

You have to parent `catsamount` to `folder` and `folder` to `player`:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local catscollected = player:WaitForChild("catsCollected")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local folder = Instance.new("Folder")
    folder.Name = "leaderstats"
    folder.Parent = player
    
    local catsamount = Instance.new("IntValue", folder)
    catsamount.Name = "Cats Found"
    catsamount.Value = 0
    catsamount.Parent = folder
    while wait(0.1) do
        catsamount.Value = 0
        for _, v in pairs(catscollected:GetChildren()) do
            catsamount.Value = catsamount.Value + 1
        end 
    end
end)
```

This is so that the folder will be added to the player after it is created - `Instance.new()` creates an instance, but it does not parent the created instance to anything so it will not appear anywhere.

Comment: it doesn't quite work. it has the same effect as the old one. When i check in the explorer the player doesn't have the folder.

Comment: I think the problem could be the part where` catscollected` is waited for - it is not defined so it probably got stuck there, unless it is defined elsewhere. Also, the folder should be added to the players on the server side, but I'm not sure if that is related to this particular problem.

Comment: Could the problem be from a script running at the same time as this one?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It could be the absence of another script that is stopping this script from working - the script waits for `catsCollected` before it is created in this script. Also, would you mind showing how it doesn't work? a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: There aren't any errors and the problem isn't with the cats collected file, the only problem is that the file (leaderstats) wont show up with the player

Comment: oh! passing the parent as the second argument to `Instance.new()` is deprecated, so it could work if you set the parent later manually.

Comment: I'm sorry I was inactive for a long time, I took a break from working on the game, concerning the code, i have tried everything, I even made a separate script to parent the folder, idk tbh